# What do scatter_kws and line_kws do in seaborn lmplot

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, seaborn

I am trying to understand the below code snippet.

```
sns.lmplot('num_items', 'total_value', data=log_carts, 
           scatter_kws={'s': 1, 'alpha': 0.1}, 
           line_kws={'lw': 2, 'color': '#4682b4'})
```

I understand that `lmplot` gives a regression line for the variables `'num_items'` and `'total_value`' from the dataframe `'log_carts'` after plotting a scatter plot. But I couldn't understand what does `scatter_kws` and `line_kws` do to the plot. I searched the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) of lmplot but it just says these two arguments are "additional keyword arguments to pass to `plt.scatter` and `plt.plot`" which doesn't help for me. I am looking for explanation for every element used in those two arguments.

Comment: You find the explanations in the matplotlib documentation for [`plt.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) and [`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html). `lw` is a short form for "linewidth".

Comment: What is meaning of kws?

Comment: @BhavukChawla It seems to be short for *keywords*, referring to that it holds *additional keyword arguments*. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html

Answer (score 9):

Those are linked to the plot and line that appear in the figure. If we use `scatter_kws={"s": 780}` meaning the greater value given, the greater plot/node. If we use `line_kws={"lw":5}` meaning the greater the value given, the thicker the line.

for example:

```
sns.lmplot('Flour', 'Sugar', data=coba, hue='Type',
       palette='Set1', fit_reg=True, scatter_kws={"s": 780}, line_kws={"lw":5});
```

[image]

```
sns.lmplot('Flour', 'Sugar', data=coba, hue='Type',
       palette='Set1', fit_reg=True, scatter_kws={"s": 1000}, line_kws={"lw":30});
```

[image]

I took the program from https://github.com/adashofdata/muffin-cupcake

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking at how to improve the line styling of `seaborn` chart.

There are more options on to this.

For instance, to set some additional styling on line you could do (for a dashed line):

```
sns.lmplot('Flour', 'Sugar', data=coba, hue='Type', palette='Set1', fit_reg=True, scatter_kws={"s": 780},\
    line_kws={"lw":25, 'linestyle':'--'});
```

You could find all possible settings here: [matplotlib docs for line styling](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline)